# Is there a way to turn off pinned tabs in Safari (Mac)?

Tags: safari, tabs

I would like to turn off the Pinned Tabs feature in Safari on Mac (11.6.3). I thought I would like the feature, but I don't - not only does it not behave like other browsers (purposeful design decision I realize), but tabs are persisted, even after I pin different tabs and/or restart the browser (probably a bug, but a frustrating one). I suspect that the latter issue can be fixed by clearing the cache and cookies, but just want to confirm the fact that nothing else an be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpin a tab by right clicking it and choosing the option to unpin it.

You cannot disable the feature. However, if you don't pin tabs then it won't interfere with your browsing otherwise.

Comment: This is what I suspected. I will leave the question open for a little while to see if other answers come in.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to disable the feature? What is the issue if you just don't use it?

Comment: It must be some sort of bug, but even if I don't use it, the pinned tabs from a previous session (several sessions ago) resurface. I know I can remove them, but it is annoying to have to do all of the time. Perhaps with a new Apple update this will be fixed. Clearing the cache and restarting the browser might help too.

Comment: I've never seen that behavior, so unfortunately I can't help you. When I close pinned tabs they always stay gone.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you might consider worth looking into is to check if you have iCloud sync enabled for Safari data. A few months back, I got an issue in which Safari tabs from previous sessions kept reopening, others keep loading-back, and that kind of stuff. It was all due to an iCloud sync setting.